# Is it possible to inject the proper type without constructing or resolving an instance of it in the unity config?

Tags: c#, unity-container

**DbContext Registrations**

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext, MobileEntities>(GetLifetime());
container.RegisterType<DbContext, AuthenticationEntities>("AuthDb", GetLifetime());
```

**Generic Repository Registration**

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IReadOnlyRepository<>), typeof(ReadOnlyRepository<>), GetLifetime());
container.RegisterType(typeof(IReadOnlyRepository<>), typeof(ReadOnlyRepository<>), "ReadOnlyAuth", GetLifetime(), new InjectionConstructor(
    container.Resolve<DbContext>("AuthDb")
));
```

The above repository takes a `DbContext` as its only parameter. I have multiple contexts that I want to inject based on the generic parameter provided. **Is it possible to inject the proper DbContext type without constructing or resolving an instance of it in the unity config?**

```
container.RegisterType<IUserPermissionService, UserPermissionService>(GetLifetime(), new InjectionConstructor(
    container.Resolve<IReadOnlyRepository<Customer>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
    container.Resolve<IReadOnlyRepository<VisitPlan>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
    container.Resolve<IReadOnlyRepository<UserBranch>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
    container.Resolve<IReadOnlyRepository<UserRoute>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
    container.Resolve<IReadOnlyRepository<UserDriverNumber>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
    container.Resolve<IReadOnlyRepository<UserActivity>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
    container.Resolve<IReadOnlyRepository<UserRole>>("ReadOnlyAuth")
));
```

Can I configure it so that the `Resolve<>` calls above aren't executed until the registration they are apart of are resolved? i.e. Can I configure it such that it only executes `container.Resolve<DbContext>("AuthDb")`  when a request to resolve 'ReadOnlyAuth' is made.

Comment: You can use `DependencyOverride` and pass current instance of `DbContext` when you try to resolve `IReadOnlyRepository<>`, but if you want to move it from unity config, you probably should have the `IUnityContainer` and directly invoke resolve of `IReadOnlyRepository<>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ResolvedParameter` `InjectionMember` to indicate that you wish to resolve the value at a later time.  A resolver will be created that will use the name and type to obtain the dependency at resolve time.

```
container.RegisterType<IUserPermissionService, UserPermissionService>(
    GetLifetime(), 
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IReadOnlyRepository<Customer>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
        new ResolvedParameter<IReadOnlyRepository<VisitPlan>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
        new ResolvedParameter<IReadOnlyRepository<UserBranch>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
        new ResolvedParameter<IReadOnlyRepository<UserRoute>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
        new ResolvedParameter<IReadOnlyRepository<UserDriverNumber>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
        new ResolvedParameter<IReadOnlyRepository<UserActivity>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
        new ResolvedParameter<IReadOnlyRepository<UserRole>>("ReadOnlyAuth")
    ));
```

In these cases an `InjectionFactory` can be used as well:

```
container.RegisterType<IUserPermissionService, UserPermissionService>(
    GetLifetime(), 
    new InjectionFactory(c =>
    {
        new UserPermissionService(
            c.Resolve<IReadOnlyRepository<Customer>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
            c.Resolve<IReadOnlyRepository<VisitPlan>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
            c.Resolve<IReadOnlyRepository<UserBranch>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
            c.Resolve<IReadOnlyRepository<UserRoute>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
            c.Resolve<IReadOnlyRepository<UserDriverNumber>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
            c.Resolve<IReadOnlyRepository<UserActivity>>("ReadOnlyAuth"),
            c.Resolve<IReadOnlyRepository<UserRole>>("ReadOnlyAuth")
    }));
```

If you use an injection factory you do get compile time checking to ensure that the constructor arguments are of the correct types.

Comment: Dang. I just figured out I could do it with `InjectionFactory` but this looks so much simpler haha.